# Setting Raspberry Pi up for more than one usage

Tags: boot, sd-card, software-installation, setup

I am new to Raspberry pi and super excited to start using it. My first raspberry pi project is going to essentially be a entertainment system connected to the tv at all times. First, I will be installing RetroPie so I can emulate old games - when completing this process, it seems the Raspberry Pi boots into the newly installed application. My question is, is it possible to choose the application I want to boot in to? So basically, on boot, I would like to have the option to open Retro Pie OR maybe some video streaming app (for example) OR some music streaming app (for example) - and if I decide to choose the emulator app for example, I can go back to 'menu' and choose the music streaming app (preferably without rebooting).

I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im guessing you mean multi-booting it? Like a PC or laptop that has two OS's on it? It might be possible using a custom NOOBS. RetroPi, Kodi, Raspbian Pixel, the likes.

Comment: The only problem with the above is rebooting, which I now see you would prefer not to have.